# Did the Prussian king Friedrich Wilhelm IV. (1795 - 1861) ever write: "Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen" = "The people makes me sick"?

Tags: quotes, sources, prussia, primary-source, press

Where does the Prussian king write "Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen" = "The people makes me sick," as claimed in 6:26 in [Die Revolution von 1848 I musstewissen Geschichte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOliGpu0H3U)?

[image: screenshot of video attributing quote to the king]

The video has been watched by 1.4 million at the time of writing.

I found this wording only in a famous mockery:

- [Flugblätter und Flugschriftensammlung 1848/1849 - Nr_030 Lithographie, Karikatur, Friedrich Wilhelm IV., 1847](https://www.sammlungen.hu-berlin.de/objekte/sammlung-von-flugblaettern-und-flugschriften/37568/), which shows only one "Spottblatt auf die Eröffnungsrede des Königs zum Vereinigten Landtag im April 1847" (= "mockery of the king's opening speech to the 'Vereinigter Landtag' [~ United Parliament] in April 1847" with this wording.
- ["Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen" Friedrich Wilhelm IV. von Preußen zur Eröffnung des "Vereinigten Landtags" am 11. April 1847](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/item/7FUSJCGZYBORP3G32PLIHSYQPLKKPBCV)

[image: cartoon image of king regurgitating onto the masses]

I became suspicious at the coarse expression since in German, this sounds much too cheap for a king. I do not like to put it here even as a quotation, since in German, this is bad colloquial language and should rather not be uttered at all. I could not imagine this to be written by the king because the wording also does not fit his writing and speaking style in other sources known to me:

- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Wilhelm_IV.
- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_mein_Volk_und_an_die_deutsche_Nation
- https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/warum-verzichtete-friedrich-wilhelm-iv--auf-die-kaiserkrone--deutschland
- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Moritz_Arndt: "Der preußische König Friedrich Wilhelm IV. hatte Arndt schon vor der Konstituierung der Versammlung geschrieben, dass er die von einem demokratischen Parlament angebotene Krone nicht annehmen werde." - which does not sound like a coarse wording at all, without having read it.
- https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/warum-verzichtete-friedrich-wilhelm-iv--auf-die-kaiserkrone--deutschland

The wording seems to belong to the caricature alone, never written by the king. If that is true, and if the king got to know about this video, he would probably turn over in his grave in anger. After longer search, I have not found any letter or speech in which the Prussian king utters this.

Has the Prussian king Friedrich Wilhelm IV. (1795 - 1861) ever written: "Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen" = "The people makes me sick"?

- In this wording, not just as a summary of someone mocking.
- And if so, where and when? (Likely around 1847/48.)

##### Grammar side note: "the people make" or "the people makes"?

*This question was changed to the wording "The people make me sick". I changed it back since I guess that it is right for "Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen". "Volk" is the people as a singular. Since English is not my mother tongue, I am not fully sure, but on the other hand, I tried to get advice from English speakers, and they did not seem to understand it:*

- *[German Singular "Volk" in English: "Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen" = "The people make me sick" or "The people makes me sick"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609503/german-singular-volk-in-english-das-volk-ist-mir-zum-kotzen-the-people-m) (this one was removed from the English Language and Usage SE (ELU SE) so that it is now back at the wrong German Language SE and closed. Before, it had been moved to ELU SE where it was closed since the native readers were unable to dig into this.*
- *Here is a remainder of my check why the question was closed. [The singular of "the peoples" is "the people". Like in "the essence of a people". Was the question closed after a misunderstanding?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15638/was-the-question-closed-after-a-misunderstanding-is-there-no-singular-of-the-p)*

*With "people" as plural, it has another meaning in German (= "die Menschen/Leute"), which is not meant here. Thus, I take the English plural, "the peoples" (= "die Völker") and make it the singular: "the people" (= "das Volk").*

Comment: A more precise claim (from a Google snippet): Jürgen Lodemann, *Lortzing: Leben und Werk des dichtenden, komponierenden und singenden Publikumslieblings, Familienvaters und komisch tragischen Spielopernweltmeisters aus Berlin*, Steidl 2000, p. 521: " Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen « , schreibt der Preußenkönig im Frühjahr 1848 an seinen Bruder Wilhelm nach England und verachtet die Farben , die dieses Volk als Freiheitsfarben feiert " I don't see a supporting footnote with a proper citation, though. It's possible the snippet cuts off before the relevant reference.

Comment: @njuffa That sounds as if it was true, that he wrote it to his brother. Which could be the only way, since in any other public letter or talk, such a wording would be too coarse and fall back on him, while to a brother, it can be imagined. Could you make it an answer? I do not need to see the primary source for this, I just do not have it, but this source is enough.

Comment: If this is indeed a quote from correspondence between Friedrich Wilhelm and his brother Wilhelm, I would expect it to be included in: Winfried Baumgart (ed.), *König Friedrich Wilhelm IV. und Wilhelm I. Briefwechsel 1840–1858.* Brill 2013, 583 pp. I have perused other published correspondence of Friedrich Wilhelm, but haven't found anything yet that is even close to the statement in question.

Comment: @njuffa For me, it is already clear that next time, I should open https://books.google.de/ and search for the quote there, not just in my daily non-Google search engine.

Comment: I do not intend to write an answer based on just one Google snippet from a book (i.e. without even textual context). I consider recourse to primary sources extremely important, because books on historical matters already contain too many (IMHO) inaccurate / questionable claims that are perpetuated because authors simply quote previous authors without skepticism and without going back to check the primary sources to ensure accuracy.

Comment: What makes me suspicious in this instance is that I cannot find any reference to this supposed statement by the king prior to the 1970s. Maybe it is a modern dramatized paraphrasation.

Comment: @njuffa It is indeed strange why the primary source is not just on the net. It is quite famous. I find something in "Der Spiegel - Ausgaben 6-9 - Seite 52": 'Für seine Untertanen hatte der Monarch dennoch nur Verachtung übrig : ,, Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen . " Und wenig später schöpfte der Hohenzoller schon wieder Hoffnung : „ Die Reichsfarben mußte ich freiwillig aufstecken , um Alles zu retten . Ist der Wurf gelungen , so lege ich sie wieder ab " , schrieb er an seinen Bruder Wilhelm .'

Comment: And another hint that he said / wrote it 6 days before the revolution: Jenny Marx: Ihr Leben mit Karl Marx: "... das Aufbegehren „seiner“ Untertanen auf den Punkt: „Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen“. Sechs Tage später, so das Geschehen aus heutiger Sicht, „treffen Militär und Volksmassen aufeinander. Erste Todesopfer sind die Folge."

Comment: For all we know at this point, this supposed statement by Friedrich Wilhelm may be as (a-)historical as Marie Antoinette's supposed statement "Let them eat cake". As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_them_eat_cake) points out in that case: " *While the phrase is commonly attributed to Marie Antoinette, it was coined by 1765, when she was 9 years old and had never been to France, and it was only attributed to her decades after her death. It is unlikely that she ever said it.* "

Comment: @njuffa A hint that it might just be attributed later is that the letter to his brother might not have been known to the public, but the mockery was published in 1847/48. The writer would need to know about that letter to make a caricature of it. And another alerting thing is that the public media then and now would like him to have said it since it makes it easier to proclaim a pure democracy without a King's Divine Grace.

Comment: I disagree that "kotzen" is so bad that it "should rather not be uttered at all". E.g. there is a famous quote by Max Liebermann whom one would certainly count as upper class intellectual. Agree that it is quite vulgar and indicates strong disgust or anger though.

Comment: @Jan This might depend on the region in Germany, not on the class. Some people would never say or write the word or the proverb. It might be more normal in the East. It is just as in some parts, you would never curse or say the sh* word. Most say "sich übergeben" or "erbrechen". It might also be the Berlin language to say it like that, Berlin is known as less formal (Berliner Schnauze = Berlin snout), so that the king might perhaps - perhaps - perhaps - have written it. Even though I cannot imagine it when reading anything else of his letters or speeches.

Comment: Political caricatures are rarely based on actual quotes, but on the essence of what was said. ["Das Volk ist mir zum Kotzen" Friedrich Wilhelm IV. von Preußen zur Eröffnung des " Vereinigten Landtags" am 11. April 1847 - Deutsche Digitale Bibliothek](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/item/7FUSJCGZYBORP3G32PLIHSYQPLKKPBCV) and [Nr_030 Lithographie, Karikatur, Friedrich Wilhelm IV., 1847](https://www.sammlungen.hu-berlin.de/objekte/sammlung-von-flugblaettern-und-flugschriften/37568/).

Comment: @njuffa If the letter is from spring 1848, then the  lithograph of late spring of 1847 could not of used it as its source.

Comment: **Barf** may be a more literal translation of *Kotzen*: [BARF | English meaning - Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/barf): *The smell was so disgusting it made me want to barf*. 'ist ... zum Kotzen' is a strong term still comonly used today. [macht mich krank](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/macht+mich+krank.html): *It makes me sick*: is a less stronger version of the same.

Comment: @MarkJohnson No need to point out the obvious. BTW, do you have access to the book by W. Baumgart? It would be useful to establish whether Friedrich Wilhelm wrote *anything resembling* the statement attributed to him in his correspondence with his brother. The king's speech of 1847 is [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Thronrede_Sr_Maj_des_K%C3%B6nigs_von_Preu%C3%9Fe/uxoe0OlB86wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Thron-Rede++1847&printsec=frontcover), and shows the king defiant and stubborn, but also invokes the theme of love between king and people repeatedly. I don't get "zum Kotzen" from that.

Comment: @njuffa I don't have s copy of the book and found no further reference to the letter. Based on the OP's reply 'but this source is enough', I think it is important to meantion this. After the events of March 1848, it should come as no surprise that Friedrich Wilhelm IV wrote this to his brother. But not in 1847 when the political caricatur was published.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, I was wrong with that second source to be enough. It seems even quite likely to me that he never wrote it. I vaguely remember that the mockery also came from the strong democratic side or so, so that they were fully against the king. Putting your last comment together with the rest, it seems quite likely that he did not write it, and the only way to get around it is that he might have said it somewhere, not in a written speech. Which still would not fit to his understanding of his role (loving the people, guided by god)

Comment: @MCW In German **Volk** is always singular ([Volk ᐅ Rechtschreibung, Bedeutung, Definition, Herkunft | Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Volk)). The peaple of one country ; Plural: *die Völker Afrikas*: the peaple of the countries in Africa.

Comment: This edit is unclear: "(Volk ᐅ Rechtschreibung, Bedeutung, Definition, Herkunft | Duden). The peaple of one country ; Plural: die Völker Afrikas: the people of the countries in Africa." There is a plural of "Volk", it is "Völker". I wonder why a native English speaker edits something without knowing German well enough. Why is it so hard for the English natives to just understand this singular "people" here? It is one of the easy starters when you learn English as a German. And there is no need to write the whole "... Duden" tail.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer because **it only deals with the caricature**, but also to long for a comment.

As pointed out by @njuffa, the caricature of barfing Friedrich Wilhelm IV is about the opening speech for Prussia's "[United Diet](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erster_Vereinigter_Landtag)" that he held on April 11th, 1847. Some notable items in this context are

- The liberals had expected some liberalization, more representation and a constitution. Friedrich Wilhelm rejected all of these. He explicitely pointed out that the diet was not going to be a parliament and implicitely that it should not expect much respect from him. (according to Christopher Clark, Revolutionary Spring, p. 259).
- Friedrich Wilhelm IV was known as "Champagnerfritze". In fact, that seems to be another title for that caricature. He was rumored to have alcohol problems and the caricature also shows a bottle of champaign. Also note the tipsy [All-seeing Eye](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence) left of the king, and the crown that looks like a [cap and bells](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_and_bells) on the right. Throwing up is a well-known symptom of an acute alcohol intoxication.
- "kotzen" or "sich auskotzen" can be used as synonym for "to rant" ([source](https://www.dwds.de/wb/auskotzen), also entry for "kotzen" II/2/d [here](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/kotzen)).

Given all this, the caricature might be more about about Friedrich Wilhelm making hardline politics under the influence, and not necessarily imply that Friedrich Wilhelm IV is disgusted by his people.

Comment: Often you should not trust your understanding of a caricature at first sight. Though this comment is not an answer, it is still very helpful knowing that this caricature might point at an alcohol problem as well. With this wording and image, the author would put himself and his movement in a rather bad light as well. And knowing about the alcohol problem, one might also understand how people might have attributed this remark to the king just a few years and decades later. In a time when primary sources still did not count so much. As said above, we clearly need the primary source here.